# Cookies.txt looks good but doesn't work

Tags: python-2.7, cookies, mechanize, mozilla, autologin

I'm trying to use Python to log in to a website and save the cookies.txt file, and it doesn't work. But I think I'm very close!

The cookies.txt file looks like this after I've ran the Python script:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://www.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html
# This is a generated file!  Do not edit.

website.com     FALSE   /   FALSE       PHPSESSID   ejFRMWtNc0YwYjdVeXQ4c25NWUUvOC9CcVZXUnV4eFhjNnlITGs...
```

When I log in to the same website and manually export it from Firefox, it looks like this:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://www.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html
# This is a generated file!  Do not edit.

website.com     FALSE   /   FALSE   0   SRLOGIN OfHFowieHRHizaoriK
website.com     FALSE   /   FALSE   0   PHPSESSID   L2tCdzNoZnhXQ09DV0FZUk4zc1pxSXhJS2ZvRDNjeTNlUU9WQlVvOGlRNW9mSXdGTFZyd...
```

So the difference is that the latter file has two lines, and the '0', which I believe refers to the cookie's timeout (and is thus set to not expire).

Here's the Python script I use to create the cookies.txt file:

```
cj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=0)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla')]
br.open('http://website.com')
for f in br.forms():
    print f
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['user[username]'] = 'john' 
br.form['user[password]'] = 'secret'
response = br.submit()        
cj.save(cookie_filename, ignore_discard=True, ignore_expires=True)
```

Comment: Anyone out there?? :(

Comment: have you tried with setting the proper user agent string?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! What do you mean by 'proper' user agent string? Pardon my ignorance, I hope you can help!